# Include curl library for C++ in dll file

Tags: c++, dll, curlpp

I'm writing a dll as a mod for Skyrim, however I need to use an external library as well. The library I need is the curl library for C++ (curlpp). Skyrim will only load the one DLL I create, therefore I need to have the entire library be compiled into the DLL file along with my code. I've never done this before, so I'm kind of lost on how to do this. Could I just copy the files from the curlpp library into my project?

If anyone could clarify the process needed I'd be very grateful.

So to recap, I'll have my own code, and the library. Those 2 should be merged into a single DLL when compiling.

Thanks!

Comment: How about just calling `LoadLibrary` in your primary `DllMain`...?

Comment: @gha.st - Calling LoadLibrary from DLL main is forbidden.  See the docs for DllMain()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include the libcurl library code directly into your DLL, as libcurl is open-source.

Or you could compile libcurl into its own DLL (or find a 3rd party precompiled DLL) and have your DLL statically link to it.  That way, if libcurl fails to load at runtime, your mod DLL will also fail to load, which Skyrim can detect and handle as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to link it statically

Comment: @Qub1 any code examples where I can find how to import curl DLL into another DLL?